# Узнать номер секунды из списка

Tags: python

Есть значение даты и времени из списка:
либо такое -
`['2021-10-21T15:26:34.308269+00:00']` или могу заменить на такое значение `[1634829994308]`.
Как узнать номер секунды (можно взять любой вариант - у меня оба есть в списках)?

Comment: Номер секунды - это что, 34 в данном случае?

Comment: 34 да .........

Comment: print("['2021-10-21T15:26:34.308269+00:00']".split(':')[2][0:2])

Comment: `1634829994308 // 1000 % 60`

Comment: @GrAnd Кстати, да, если это миллисекунды с начала эпохи, то логично и так тоже, даже без парсинга )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2021-10-21T15:26:34.308269+00:00')
print(dt.second)
# 34

dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1634829994308/1000)
print(dt.second)
# 34
```

Comment: почему делите на 1000 во втором?

Comment: @Alexandr А где-то тут мне уже попадалось, что нужно делить, но на сколько именно - я не помнил. При делении именно на 1000 преобразуется правильно. Скорее всего у автора вопроса `timestamp` в миллисекундах, а `datetime` хочет в секундах, поэтому так.